# Relacionar Datos para inventario

Tags: mysql, sql

Buena tarde tengo un problema a la hora de relacionar datos en mysql para un sistema que ando desarrollando, la duda que tengo es que la empresa a la que le ando trabajando compra por mayoreo sus productos, y los vende de la misma manera, pero ando buscando la manera ingresar los productos en distintos niveles, por ejemplo de compra:
-Compra de 1 Caja de Lapiceros que contiene  20 Cajitas y Cada caja contiene 12 lapiceros, en esta compra observamos 3 niveles
Otro ejemplo seria cuando se compran pastillas medicas
-Compra de 1 Caja  y cada caja tiene 20 cajitas y cada cajita tiene 12 blisters y cada blister 12 pastillas en esto vemos 4 niveles
Al momento de la venta se tendria que poder hacer de estas distintas formas ya se por unidad, blister, cajita o caja.
El problemas que tengo es como modelar la base de datos sabiendo que podremos tener distintos niveles de compra segun la presentacion que se compre

Comment: Puedes hacer es un programa que transforme producto de una unidad a otra. En tu catálogo vas a tener los 3 niveles como 3 diferentes productos (Caja de 20 cajas, Caja de 12 lapiceros, Lapicero pieza). Y si lo que quieren es vender lapiceros, transformas la existencia de caja de lapiceros a lapiceros pieza. Es decir tu modelo es normal, serían 3 diferentes productos, sólo transformarías de uno a otro la existencia.

Comment: Bienvenido..Mr. SYS..., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que podrias realizar una tabla que alimente de un maestro desde un campo me explico
Ejemplo:
Los campos serian estos:

```
Id | nombreproducto | padreproducto|
1     pastillas                           0
2     aspirinas 1×24                1
3     antigripales                     1
4     1 caja lapicero                0
5     20 cajitas                        4
6      caja12lapiceros            5
```

Asi seria la forma de llenarlos donde id seria el correlativo de la tabla "padreproducto" seria como lo dice su nombre el id padre al cual pertenece el producto...

Creo que te podria servir....

Saludos

Comment: No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar, las preguntas deben realizarse de acuerdo a lo definido en el [help] , [ask]. Orientemos a los usuarios a preguntar correctamente para que las respuestas sean valiosas no solo para el que pregunta si no a toda la comunidad, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno los productos q se adquieran se almacenan con su unidad de medida y descripcion, acompañados de un codigo q los diferencia, y puedes almacenar codigo - descripcion- unidad de medida - precio, cantidad, etc

> 00001 - aspirina 150 mg. Blister 1 x 24 - blister - $2.00,1000
>   00002
>   - aspirina 200 mg. Blister 1 x 18 - blister - $3.00, 3000
>   00003 - cinta metrica 6m - unidad - $5.00, 400

El ejemplo anterior refleja q tienes aspirina de varios tipos, se contabilixan por blisters y el caso de las cintas metricas, se contabilizan por unidades.

Es un ejemplo muy muy sencillo para q tengas una idea de como puedes organizar tus datos, pero dependeran en gran medida de la informacion q tu empresa quiere almacenar

Comment: No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar, las preguntas deben realizarse de acuerdo a lo definido en el [help] , [ask]. Orientemos a los usuarios a preguntar correctamente para que las respuestas sean valiosas no solo para el que pregunta si no a toda la comunidad, saludos.